# Combine multiple elements on .attr

Tags: jquery, performance

Is there a better way for writing this jquery code by combining the elements into 1 or 2 lines?

```
jQuery('#pinfo').attr('href', 'mailto:roaming@domain.com'  );
jQuery('#pinfo').attr('class','pullup');
jQuery('#prelated').attr('href', 'mailto:roaming@domain.com'  );
jQuery('#prelated').attr('class','pullup');
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions**, **why they didn't work**, and the expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set multiple attributes by [providing the key-value pairs as an object](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributes).  JQuery also allows you to set attributes on multiple targets -- just select them using `$("selector1, selector2")`.

```
jQuery('#pinfo, #prelated').attr({ 
    href: "mailto:roaming@domain.com", 
    class: "pullup" 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JSON style object to change values for an element. Here's an example:

```
$("a").attr({
   href: "foo",
   id: "bar"
});
```

Each of the values will be separated by commas. This method is easier to understand if you look into JSON, so here is a link to some info on that: http://www.w3schools.com/json/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#pinfo, #preleated').attr('href','mailto:roaming@domain.com').addClass('pullup');
```